# Need someone to clear up my mind about the CP of Pokemon

Tags: pokemon-go

After playing for a few days, i have some questions about the CP of Pokemons. My friends and i did some tests and here what we got:

1. Im lv18 and  catched a magikarp 100CP. My friend is lv18 too, and he catched one with 120CP. We max CP of each one and evolve them. Then the result is my Gyrados has 1469CP and his Gyrados is 1462CP. Only 7CP different not too much..
   -> So i think that each lv has a limit CP for each pokemon. That means 2 players with the same level will have the same CP cap. Even if the beginning CP of 2 pokemons is different they still will have the same amount of CP when we max them?
2. On the otherside, another friend of mine catched 2 magikarp. One is 130CP, one is 120CP. He is lvl20. He max the one with 130CP and evolve it into a 1695CP Gyrados. The one with 120CP, he power up it to 130CP, evolve and max it, reach only 1665CP.
   -> So my idea about the CP cap of each player is wrong? Cuz if my theory is right these 2 gyrados should have the same CP (maybe theres a distance but not too much like this).

Any idea here?

Comment: I believe that XS and XL also affect the CP/Health growth of a pokemon. This might be a relevant factor in this case.

Comment: Actually theres not much differences between their size i have some screenshot here but dunno how to up it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to check myself, but according to some people, extra size and weight (XL or XS) do affect HP and CP

Check the size of your thow maxed out pokemons.

Also, the upgrade work steps by step. So if the next upgrade gives +10% (of max CP) and your pokemon is at 81%, it will got at 91% then blocked while starting at 89% you will end up at 99%.

Comment: I have checked the weight and height, an eevee with xl in both weight and height has 459cp and 59hp. Meanwhile, an eevee with normal size has 424cp and 61hp. So i think size doesnt effect cp nor hp.

Comment: U mean the upgrading system is random. I thought that it will auto adjust the cp so u can reach the same max CP for 2 pokemons of each kind. So if what u say is right then i can understand the difference in CP now. In the test 1 when power up i got more CP than my friend so that even we started with a far distance but we still ended up with same cp amount ! Thanks for that info !